# Clone a div and replace child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with the following content:

```
<div class="payment-form napthe">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Mã thẻ</label></td>
                <td><label>Serial</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="prepaidcard_code"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="prepaidcard_serial"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="result">Sai định dạng query</span></td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>                         
</div>
```

I want to clone this div using jQuery but make the text of the last element `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` empty.

I want the result after cloning like this:

```
<div class="payment-form napthe">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Mã thẻ</label></td>
                <td><label>Serial</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="prepaidcard_code"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="prepaidcard_serial"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="result"></span></td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>                         
</div>
```

Comment: *What have you tried so far?*

Comment: Why is this Q marked as off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should post what you've already tried...

Anyway, this should work

```
var $clone = $('.payment-form.napthe').clone();
$('.result', $clone).empty();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var cloned = $('.payment-form.napthe').clone();
cloned.find('.result').empty(); // or .find('tr:last td span').text('');
```

References

http://api.jquery.com/?s=%3Alast

http://api.jquery.com/text/

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: `.find('.result').empty()` makes a bit more sense, and readable to boot.

Comment: @ahren updated ty :) i didn't see that class :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var clone = $(".payment-form.napthe").html();

$("#output-div").html(clone); // output the cloned HTML somewhere
$("#output-div tr:last-child span").html(""); // empty contents of span of last <tr>
```

If you need to do multiple clones, you can also do:

```
$("#output-div").append(clone);
```

#output-div is just something I made up to represent a space you want to place the clone(s). It could be something like `body`